# How can I make my VBA code more efficient?

Tags: excel, vba

I am running a Sub Routine by using `Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate` Worksheet Event. I am experiencing major lag and slow execution of my Sub Routine. My Sub Routine formats a column on a Pivot Table if the Cell value meets the condition of my code. How can I avoid experiencing slow execution times?

**Sub Routine**

```
Option Explicit

Sub setFormatting()
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Dim c As Range, x As Integer

    For x = 13 To 768
        For Each c In Sheet3.Cells(x, 2)
            If c = "ü" Then
                c.Font.Name = "Wingdings"
                c.Font.Bold = True
                c.Font.Size = 14
                c.Font.Color = RGB(0, 176, 80)
            ElseIf c = "X" Then
                c.Font.Bold = True
                c.Font.Size = 12
                c.Font.Color = RGB(247, 79, 79)
            ElseIf c = "RM Apprvd" Then
                c.Font.Color = RGB(212, 140, 10)
                c.Font.Bold = True
            End If
        Next
    Next
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

**Code Calling Sub Routine**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)   
    setFormatting    
End Sub
```

Comment: That double `For` loop looks problematic. It may not contribute much to inefficiency, but it's certainly an antipattern that you're doing. Would be better to implement a single `For Each c in Sheet3.Range(Sheet3.Cells(13,2), Sheet3.Cells(768, 2)).Cells`.

Comment: I don't work with PT very much, but I also suspect that tying this to the PivotTableUpdate event is potentially problematic. Can you show the code for that event handler?

Comment: @DavidZemens I modified my post to include the `Worksheet Event`

Comment: Every time the PT updates, that loop is evaluating and potentially altering the font formats of 755 cells on the sheet. Is that what you expect? Can you try using conditional format rules instead of VBA here?

Comment: @DavidZemens I used VBA because I am unable to change the font property of my pivot table when using Conditional Formatting. `"ü"` is supposed to be a green checkmark when assigned the font property of `"Wingdings"`. I cant seem to do this when using Conditional Formatting

Comment: @BigBen I used vba because I cant change the font style of the cells with Conditional Formatting

Comment: Ah... I often use the arrow icon set with the numeric value of 1 as the green arrow. It's probably a stretch to apply that approach, if your underlying data is "ü" - but I'm kind of curious if it's possible. Note that the 2nd and 3rd parts could probably be conditional formatting, but again I don't have your data in front of me to suggest the best approach overall.

Comment: @BigBen I narrowed down my Sub Routine, it only formats font style now, runs so much quicker. I am letting Conditional Formatting assign the colors. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I am allowing Conditional Formatting apply the following properties:
font color & font style. My Sub Routine only updates the Font Name, now it runs without any problems.

Here is my updated code:

```
Sub setFormatting()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False

Dim c As Range

For Each c In Sheet3.Range(Sheet3.Cells(13, 2), Sheet3.Cells(768, 2)).Cells

    If c = "ü" Then

        c.Font.Name = "Wingdings"

    End If

Next

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use `AutoFilter` and `SpecialCells` methods.

```vb
Sub setFormatting()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With Range(Sheet3.Cells(12,2), Sheet3.Cells(768,2))
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="ü"
        with .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Font
            .Name = "Wingdings"
            .Bold = True
            .Size = 14
            .Color = RGB(0, 176, 80)
        End With
        .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False

        .AutoFilter 1, "X"
        with .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Font
            .Bold = True
            .Size = 12
            .Color = RGB(247, 79, 79)
        End With
        .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False

        .AutoFilter 1, "RM Apprvd"
        with .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Font
            .Bold = True
            .Color = RGB(212, 140, 10)
        End With
        .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```